# Create New Dictionary based on Existing Dictionary matching a variable with Keys in Existing Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have dictionary `dicts`. I have variable `ID` = `"gateway_id"`.
I want to create new dictionary `dicts2` of containing `key`, `value` pair match with variable `ID`.

Code:

```
dicts = {'gateway_id':"123","hi":"hello"}

ID = 'gateway_id'
```

New Dict: Expected Output

```
dicts2 = {'gateway_id':"123"}
```

Comment: `dicts2 = {id: dicts[id]}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
dicts = {'gateway_id':"123","hi":"hello"}
ID = 'gateway_id' # id is a python builtin

dicts2 = {ID: dicts[ID]}
```

output: `{'gateway_id': '123'}`